# What options exist for ad free web browsing on iOS?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, web-browsing, web-browser, adblock

In OS X I can use extensions in most browsers to block ads. This offers an distraction free browsing experience.

For example: In Safari, Chrome and Firefox I can use **[Adblock](http://safariadblock.com/)** or **[Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/en)**. Both extensions use filter lists which you can find [here](https://adblockplus.org/en/subscriptions). You can also manually add filters and add sites on which you accept to see ads (e.g. apple.stackexchange.com).

What options exists for ad free web browsing in iOS?

Comment: Almost all 3rd party browsers have adblock capabilities. Or jailbreak and modify the /etc/hosts file and then Safari and all the apps will have ads blocked.

Comment: Jailbroken or stock firmware?

Answer (score 3):

Try the **[Diigo Webbrowser](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/diigo-browser-chrome-like/id432838105?mt=8)**. It recently added an Ad Blocking feature that's off by default.

Comment: Looking at the app description, this seems to require an in-app purchase.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Privoxy](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://www.privoxy.org/&ei=oddJUZCjHMTNOMa8gaAI&usg=AFQjCNGe518T5LwYnr0CFE2YPlHVV_IvLw) as an ad-stripping proxy server on a Linux box such as the inexpensive Raspberry Pi featured in this article:
http://kimondo.co.uk/raspberry-pi-as-an-adblock-server-for-ipad-iphone-android-and-anything-else-on-your-network/

I have tried this and it works well. (Obviously no jailbreaking is required for this solution).

Comment: How do you set this as a proxy to all the Wifi and 3G connections you make?

Comment: The proxy settings are set for each wifi connection like so: http://www.chicagotech.net/images/ipad16.gif

Comment: I'm finding that Safari on my iPad1 crashes a whole let less often when  when using Privoxy to filter out ads and things. I guess iPad1's Safari has a lot less to deal with the ads removed and so doesn't run out of resources so often.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a jailbroken device, you can use the tweak "Adblocker" ($2) to block ads in Mobile Safari. It includes options for pre-defined blacklists and user-defined blacklists. Here's [one blog post demonstrating the tweak](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/01/05/adblocker-ad-blocking-iphone/) and [another one](http://modmyi.com/content/5873-giveaway-block-annoying-ads-safari-certain-apps-adblocker.html).

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 9 it is now possible to use official ad blockers in Safari.
For example [Adblock Fast](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adblock-fast/id1032930802)

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to adblock on the iDevices is a modified DNS-server or a DNS-Resolver. For instance it is possible to modifie the hostfile or DNS-Entrys on your router. This will only work with wifi. i dont know if it is possible to modify your DNS server for 3G connection. i think it was possible via APN settings iin ios4/5. But with iOS6 i was not able to find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

[iCab](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icab-mobile-web-browser/id308111628?mt=8) mobile contains an adblock-like filter mechanism

Answer (score 0):

There is a Kickstarter project for a hardware device called AdTrap which is supposed to solve this problem by filtering ads out in between them coming from your router and arriving at your device.

http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/600284081/adtrap-the-internet-is-yours-again

You could set up a profile/VPN to route your traffic through a filtering service or device so that you could keep using Safari and all the usual web browsing tools in iOS without needing to jailbreak or confine your browsing to one application.

Comment: `What options *exist* for ad free web browsing on iOS?`

Comment: @Dunhamzzz This actually is the only solution I would entertain for this dilemma. I use many apps that use web browsers embedded and not using mobile Safari and those apps to browse the web is a non-starter for me. I do appreciate the iOS apps that look to be a fuller featured Safari - but am willing to set up more of an infrastructure for the reasons stated here.

Comment: @bmike I was getting at the fact this product currently doesn't exist, it's scheduled for release in Feb '13 and that's only if they pass their goal.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz I totally get that - but we also are a place for even wrong answers - as long as the answerer is moving the discussion forward. What may be down voted / unuseful to some since it doesn't ship - might still be the best answer for others. Your comment is proper, correct and in the right place - just wanted to reinforce that despite some downvoting it - it's also worth supporting for others.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Weblock app](http://www.weblockapp.com) ($1.99). I am affiliated with the product so check into other reviews if you wish. I feel it works great.

[image]

Comment: The problem with Weblock is that works only on WiFi and you need to configure for each and every WiFi network.

Comment: bleo, please disclose your affiliation with the product in the answer, so that others are aware of your connection with the app you are recommending.  (Just listing it in your profile is not enough, as many people are unlikely to check your profile.)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! @D.W. is correct - a good place to disclose a relationship with your product is in the profile. Per the [help] - "The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."

)

Comment: Let me correct a small detail in what @bmike said: you should disclose your relationship with the product in the answer (not just in your profile).

Comment: Keep in mind that Weblock proxies all your traffic through their servers.
2 problems with it:
1) It makes your browsing slower due to extra hops
2) It makes your browsing less secure because Weblock sees *everything* your do.

Answer (score 0):

## Safari

If you want to stay in Safari ecosystem, consider Adguard: https://github.com/AdguardTeam for Mac as well as iOS. If it breaks any page on iOS, hold refresh button & tap "reload without content blockers."

Taking it one step further, consider [Adguard Home](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdGuardHome) for network level ad blocking on every device connected.  This adds much more to https://pi-hole.net.

## Others

If you're willing to switch browsers, check [Brave](https://brave.com/) browser. It has built-in ad blocker but less customisability for filters. On Mac, all feature-rich content blockers like [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock#installation) of Chrome/Firefox are available to you which you cannot use on Safari.

Same goes for [Firefox](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/firefox-private-safe-browser/id989804926). You should try both and see which one works out for you.

*Not affiliated with any product.*

Answer (score -1):

Give a try to our [Speedmeup](http://www.speedmeup.net/) project. It's free and requires no app installation.

Unlike other similar solutions your trafic is not routed through slow proxies. More technical details are in [the FAQ](http://www.speedmeup.net/faq#4.1).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Can you please disclose your affiliation with the product in your profile and in the answer. The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.

Answer (score -1):

Ba.net/adblock
Dns based for iOS, mac

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score -2):

You can try the cloud proxy service at http://www.safecloudproxy.com
It is free for 1 gb / month.